# Remove item list from DB MSSQL using ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener Android

Tags: android, sql-server

I have created a database which is displayed in a ListView using an SimpleAdapter. Now, I want to show a layout which contain (edit & delete ), so when user longClick on an item of the list it will get a dialog to choose if its want to delete or to edit on this item. Now, I'm focusing on delete statement and

I have tried with this code, but it does not work for me, the program always force close when I use this code.

Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStates){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStates);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_lstview);

userDataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewUser);
List<Map<String, String>> data  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(
String[] from = {"tvId", "tvUsr", "tvPass", "tvDept","tvAuth"};
int[] to = {R.id.tvId, R.id.tvUsr, R.id.tvPass, R.id.tvDept, R.id.tvAuth};
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserListView.this, data, R.layout.userlisttemplate, from, to);
userDataListView.setAdapter(adapter);

userDataListView.setLongClickable(true);
userDataListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked item : " +adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

userDataListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     final int which_item = position;

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserListView.this);
        dialogBuilder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirmation");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Choose an option edit or delete data ?");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                // Edit
­­
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                // Delete
                data.remove(which_item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          Toast.makeText(UserListView.this, "Data has been removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.create().show();
        return true;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: When do you add the 'data' field?

Comment: The 'data' field appears to be empty. So I think there was a crash while removing it

Comment: @SeunghoKang : add 'data' field is already exist, I just put Listview.setOnItemLongClickListener code here

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I already fixed it using this code HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>)adapter.getItem(position);
                        String UserID=(String)obj.get("tvId"); and call UserID to my delete query db.